# I sent ether to the DCORP crowdsale using Coinbase, can I retrieve it?

Tags: transactions

I sent ether to the DCORP crowdsale using Coinbase, can I retrieve it?

I invested 1 Ether into the DCORP crowdsale only later to find out that they do not support coinbase ether wallets.

0xD42433A8a0A1CEB73c8ff4e432463e2ee109039d

the ERC20 token (DRP) is now linked to the address Coinbase used to send ETH with, on my behalf.
I WILL OFFER A BOUNTY OF HALF THE RECOVERED ETHER IF ANYONE CAN FIND THIS
Although I am guessing the answer is that only Coinbase can resolve this, they will only send the bot to minister to my query and I do not anticipate Coinbase will seek to resolve anything.

Comment: Hi, Mark! Did you solve the problem?